# Why did Mahler experience fin-de-siècle angst?

Tags: history

Source: [*The Complete Classical Music Guide*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0756692563) (2012). General Editor: John Burrows OBE HonRCM, edited with [Charles Wiffen](https://theconversation.com/profiles/charles-wiffen-142851). [p. 152 Bottom Right](https://books.google.com/books?id=w5hGTCM8WE0C&pg=PA152&lpg=PA152&dq=%22there+is+often+an+atmosphere+of+tension+and%22&source=bl&ots=Ua68lcTh4M&sig=E2VCohqtrPKMoxxlq0Z1RUNZDqY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjbsojIhMbbAhXErFkKHShoDBcQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22there%20is%20often%20an%20atmosphere%20of%20tension%20and%22&f=false).

> #### Music
>
> Apart from lost student chamber works,
>   Mahler’s output is virtually all symphony and
>   vocal; although an outstanding opera conductor,
>   he completed none of the three he started.
>   His style is late-Romantic, but he expanded the
>   orchestra in both sound and size (his Symphony
>   No. 8 requires 1,000 participants). However, what
>   really distinguishes a Mahler symphony is more
>   theatrical: the feeling of many voices at work and a
>   sequence of events. There is often an atmosphere
>   of tension and ***fin-de-siècle* angst** contrasted with
>   love and joy; Mahler consulted with Freud, and a
>   strong psychoanalytical—some say self-pitying—
>   aspect runs through much of his music. Sarcasm,
>   parody, and irony abound in Mahler’s mix of the
>   sublime and the ridiculous, which may explain
>   the popularity of his symphonies in the “knowing”
>   era of the late 20th century.

I read [Wikipedia on  fin-de-siècle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fin_de_si%C3%A8cle), but about what was Mahler angsty?

Answer (score 2):

The quote doesn't convey that Mahler himself was unusually angsty.  Rather, *angst* was a typical expression of of the *[fin-de-siècle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fin_de_si%C3%A8cle)* mood, a feeling of listlessness, apathy, impatience, overdevelopment, and degeneration that attended the end of the 19th century.  People were tired of the old century, and ready for a new one to begin, and like high school seniors impatient to leave for college, they felt a mixture of nostalgia and frustration.

The writer is suggesting that the harmonic tension in Mahler's polyvalent orchestrations mirrors the dominant *fin-de-siècle* mood of his time and place.

Answer (score 0):

It seems clear to je that Mahler suffered a continuing, if not continuous terror of death, which he tried to counter,nin particular by a belief in a resurrection to eternal life, most powerfully expressed in the closing movement of his symphony number 2, The Resurrection.